# brownian bridge and supremum

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

I want to show that:
$$
\sup_{u \geq 0} \frac{1}{u} \left( | B_u | - 1 \right) = \sup_{u \geq 0} \left( |B_u| - u \right) = \sup_{0 \leq u \leq 1 } b_u^2
$$ in distribution;
with $ B_u = (1+u)b_{\frac{u+1}{u}}$ where $b_u$ is a Brownian bridge.

I already proved that $ B_u $ is a Brownian motion.

From the book: "Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion" by Revuz and Yor, I concluded that I must first show that:

$$
\sup_{t \geq 0}( |B_t| - t^{\frac{p}{2}}) = \sup_{t \geq 0} \left( |B_t| \cdot \frac{1}{1 + t^\frac{p}{2}} \right)^q
\text{ in distribution with} \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1 \text{ and } B_t \text{ a Brownian motion.}
$$

Then I can take $p = q = 2$ .Which then easily gives me:

$$
\sup_{t \geq 0} ( |B_t| - t ) = \sup_{t \geq 0} \left( b_\frac{t}{1 + t} \right)^2 \text{ in distribution. Which is equal to }\sup_{0 \leq u \leq 1} ( b_u )^2 \text{in distribution}
$$

which proves the second equality.

But I'm stuck proving that: 
$$
\sup_{t \geq 0}( |B_t| - t^{\frac{p}{2}}) = \sup_{t \geq 0} \left( |B_t| \cdot \frac{1}{1 + t^\frac{p}{2}} \right)^q
\text{ in distribution}
$$

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Your previous question on the subject was put on hold as off-topic and you were explained that it was "missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level." How comes your new question (this one) completely lacks context as well?

Comment: I've the same problem too. Let's take $p=2$. I guess one way to get the distribution is this: trying to work with
$P\left( sup_{t\ge 0} |B_t |-t \le x \right)$
Now i think one has to use scaling property or time inversion in some manner in order to get to the expression on the right hand side, but $B_t - t$ is not a Brownian motion, and I don't know how to overcome this problem. 
Does anyone have some hints?

Comment: See this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1848721/.