# Evaluating the distribution involving a Brownian motion.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm trying to solve one exercise closely related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832550/brownian-bridge-and-supremum) question. Since I don't have an answer yet, I thought to post a new question with my thoughts about the problem. I hope this does not break any rule of this forum.

The problem is the following: we let $(X_u)_{u \ge 0}:=(u+1)b_{\frac{u}{u+1}},$ where $(b_u)_{0\le u \le 1}$ is a Brownian Bridge. One can show that $(X_u)_{u\ge 0}$ is a Brownian Motion. Then we want to show that

> $$ \sup_{u \geq 0} \left( |X_u| - u \right) \overset{(d)}{=} \sup_{0 \leq u \leq 1 } b_u^2.$$

What we did (me and some friends) was this: first we noticed that 
$$\sup\limits_{u\ge 0}\left(\frac{X_u}{u+1}\right)^2=\sup\limits_{u\ge 0}b_{\frac{u}{u+1}}^2 =\sup\limits_{0 \le u \le 1}b_u^2.$$
Then to show that $\sup\limits_{0 \le u \le 1}b_u^2$ and $\sup\limits_{u\ge 0}\left(\frac{X_u}{u+1}\right)^2$ are equally distributed, we tried to manipulate the distribution function of the two random variables using *time inversion* and *scaling* of the Brownian Motion. So we tried to bring the LHS of the next expression to the RHS.
$$\Bbb{P}\left( \sup\limits_{u\ge 0}\left(\frac{X_u}{u+1}\right)^2\le x\right)= \Bbb{P}\left(  \sup_{u \geq 0} \left( |X_u| - u \right)\le x\right).$$
The main problem with this is the square factor on the LHS. So, to overcome the problem, we thought it would have been great if, instead of $x$, we had a $1$. Because then,
$$\Bbb{P}\left( \sup\limits_{u\ge 0}\left(\frac{|X_u|}{u+1}\right)^2\le 1\right) = \Bbb{P}\left( \sup\limits_{u\ge 0}\left(\frac{|X_u|}{u+1}\right)\le 1\right) =\Bbb{P}\left( \sup\limits_{u\ge 0}|X_u| - u \le 1\right), $$
which is the expression we have to prove. Also, I guess we proved correctly that 
$$\Bbb{P}\left( \sup\limits_{u\ge 0}\left(\frac{X_u}{u+1}\right)^2\le 1\right) = \Bbb{P}\left( \sup\limits_{u\ge 0}\left(\frac{|X_u|}{u+1}\right)^2\le 1\right).$$

> Now we don't know how to explain the fact that we can let $x=1$, do you know first, whether this is true and secondly how to prove it?

This idea came us also, because we saw, by a scaling argument, that for a Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t \ge 0}$ and for $M > 0$,
$$\Bbb{P}\left( \sup_{s\ge 0} B_s > 1\right) = \Bbb{P}\left( \sup_{s\ge 0}B_s> M\right).$$

Comment: Mind that $\sup_{s \geq 0} B_s = \infty$ almost surely, so the very last equation in your question is not really meaningful.

Comment: @saz Yes, this is true, in fact I wrote that property with the wrong inequality sings. (Edited now) and we used it in class to prove that $\limsup_{t\to \infty} B_t = + \infty$ a.s.

Comment: I see; nice way to prove this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $x > 0$. By the scaling property, we know that

$$\tilde{X}_t := \sqrt{x} X_{t/x}$$

is a Brownian motion. Consequently, we have

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{u \geq 0} \left( \frac{|X_u|}{u+1} \right)^2 \leq x \right) &= \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{u \geq 0} \left( \sqrt{x} \frac{|X_u|}{u+1} \right)^2 \leq x^2 \right) \\ &= \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{u \geq 0} \left( \frac{|\tilde{X}_{ux}|}{u+1} \right)^2 \leq x^2 \right) \\ &= \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{u \geq 0} \left( \frac{|X_{ux}|}{u+1} \right)^2 \leq x^2 \right) \\ &= \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{u \geq 0}  \frac{|X_u|}{\frac{u}{x}+1}  \leq x \right) \\ &= \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{u \geq 0} \frac{|X_u|}{x+u} \leq 1 \right) \end{align*}$$

Since

$$ \frac{y}{x+u} \leq 1 \iff y \leq x+u \iff y-u \leq x$$

it is not difficult to see that this implies

$$ \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{u \geq 0} \left( \frac{|X_u|}{u+1} \right)^2 \leq x \right) = \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{u \geq 0} (|X_u|-u) \leq x \right).$$

This proves the desired identity for $x > 0$. For $x \leq 0$ the identity is trivial since $\sup_u |X_u|^2/(u+1)^2$ is a non-negative random variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The funny thing is that we tried to use the scaling property, but couldn't prove the third equality. I think there you substitute $u$ with $\frac{u}{x}$, right? But then I get $ux$ also in the denominator, I don't see where I'm wrong... Btw i think one power of 2 is missing in the second equality

Comment: @Bman72 stupid; I totally missed that I have to replace $u$ by $u/x$ in the denominator. I have edited my answer; I hope it's correct now ...

Comment: Thank you very much! I think your answer is perfect! We spent quite some time trying to get rid of the factor $\frac{u}{x}$ on the denominator, but weren't able to. You saved us! Have a nice evening!

Comment: @Bman72 You are welcome. :)